# Compartir variable de usuario con todos los componentes en Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, angular6

Estoy desarrollando una app con angular 6 y firebase. Tengo un servicio para el login "auth.service.ts" el cual me devuelve la promesa para verificar el estado de login del usuario.

My pregunta es si debo invocar el servicio y correr toda la promesa desde todos los componentes o hayalguna manera de poder hacerlo una vez y que los datos almacenados en una variable (digamos "user") este disponible en todos los componenetes.

Answer (score 0):

Los servicios en angular son singleton, pudiendo mantener en memoria cualquier variable para n componentes.

Para usar un servicio como singleton de varios tendrá que ser proveído desde el módulo común a varios.

La documentación sobre servicios la puedes encontrar en la propia web de angular [servicios](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4)